# Unresolved std::exception::exception(char const * const &,int)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors, linker

Following [this instruction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2007/12/10/chttpserver-not-included-in-visual-studio-2008/), I am migrating a legacy VC++ project to MSVS2017 . I'm getting the following error currently:

```
eafxisd.lib(isapi.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &,int)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc(void)" (??0bad_alloc@std@@QAE@XZ)
```

This is the only error left. Any ideas how to resolve it?

Update:
There are also some warnings, if this is relevant:

```
1>eafxisd.lib(isapi.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)) imported in function "public: virtual __thiscall std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc(void)" (??1bad_alloc@std@@UAE@XZ)
1>eafxisd.lib(isapi.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z (public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)) imported in function "public: __thiscall std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc(class std::bad_alloc const &)" (??0bad_alloc@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
```

I am linking the following standard libraries:

```
eafxisd.lib
nafxisd.lib
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
```

I ignore legacy MFC libraries:

```
mfc80d.lib
mfcs80d.lib
```

Comment: _"...The constructors exception(const char * const &message) and exception(const char * const &message, int) are Microsoft extensions to the Standard C++ Library...."_ source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/standard-library/exception-class?view=vs-2017  Have you turned of MSVC extensions in the project options?

Comment: @RichardCritten , No, "disable language extensions" is set to "No".

Comment: How about `/permissive-`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2017  Or it could be an ABI issue if you are linking a pre-built library.

Comment: @RichardCritten, no, "Conformance mode" is set to "No" - there is no `/permissive-` flag.